# Count by years from dates list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, date

I have a spreadsheet that has a column of dates in it. I want to be able to count how many cases are 2013, 2014 etc.

If they were just years, it would be easy but they are dates, hundreds of dates from 2013 - 2016. So I need a way of counting how many occurrences of each year are in the column.

I've tried countif, sumif and frequency, but none give the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(A1:A24)=2013))
```

for data like:

[image]

Similar for other years.

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but locating the 2013 result next to a 2016 date is confusing until the reader realizes it's a random location.  Might be clearer to use column C for a list of years, and then use a cell reference to the year in your formula in col D.

Comment: I managed to use this formula =COUNTIF(O:O,">1/1/2015") but then when I wanted to count up only the 2014 it also count the 2015, so I ended up putting -D5 at the end to get the correct figure. When I got to adding up 2012 I had -d5-f5-h5 at the end of my original formula. Is there an easier way?